# How do you call a NSManagedObject that is no longer a fault?

Tags: core-data, terminology

This might seem a stupid question, but I always want to use a quick word just as I use for 'fault' NSManagedObject instances. Once the fault was fired... how should we call these objects? From http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/04/24/its-not-your-fault/ I can see Apple would call this a 'fully realized NSManagedObject'. I really don't like that. 
Is there an official way of calling these objects? If there is, then this question is not subjective and I'll choose the correct answer. If there's not, this question should be closed, since there probably wouldn't be a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [our book](https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/) we call them *materialized* as in “fully materialized object” or “turning an object into a fault or materializing it causes any KVO observers to trigger”.

Comment: So would it be something like "a material"? Because a faulted NSManagedObject has the "ed" suffix, just as when saying "materialized NSManagedObject". If I'm talking about faults, should I then be talking about "materials"? Sounds a little weird. Although "materialized NSManagedObject" sounds good.

Comment: No, it's a *materialised object*. It’s true that *fault* is often used as a short form for *faulted object*, but you can't do that for *materialised object*. If you absolutely need something short, you could do *non-fault* but even that is a bit confusing.

Comment: Fare enough. Thank you.